# Unable to enumerate devices error on Windows 8.1

Tags: ios, flash, air, usb, windows-8.1

I'm tying to publish an iOS app from Flash CS6 to an USB connected iPod Touch 5G.
While compiling I'm getting the error:

```
Unable to enumerate devices
```

Then the publishing process stops.

I tried to reconnect the device and also switched USB ports (3.0 to 2.0) but the error still occurs.

How to fix it?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You can only compile for iOS from Xcode

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the latest version of iTunes for Windows. Uninstall iTunes, then reinstall the version for older video cards (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1784?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).